# Translating "to be excited to..."

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras

What is the best way to translate sentences like:

- I'm so excited to see you next week!
- He's really excited about graduation.
- We're excited to have you come visit for Christmas.

Do **emocionado** and **entusiasmado** convey the same sentiment as **excited**, or are there subtle differences in meaning?

Comment: I miss an answer with the verb _ansiar_ (or the noun _ansias_ f.pl.), which seems to me like a less _literal_ translation: ansío verte, ansía graduarse, esperamos con ansias que vengas para Navidad.

Answer (score 3):

"emocionado" sounds a little less formal, just a little. But they both have the same meaning when they are used to translate "excited to" or "exited about"

As long as you don't translate it as "estoy muy excitado de verte la siguiente semana" it should be fine XD

However, to express a strong feeling (or emotion) you can only use "emocionado". For example, you could say:

> "la pelicula fué muy emocionante" or "La película me dejó emocionado"

but you can't say:

> "la película fue muy entusiasmante" nor "la película me dejó entusiasmado" (it's correct but it doesn't make much sense)

Comment: I suggest you explain briefly why "excitado" should be avoided.  E.g., "excitado" has a specific sexual meaning in Spanish.

Answer (score 3):

I'll tell you one secret - at least from a linguistic point of view, Spaniards are really not likely to convey their emotions as directly as English speakers do.

Rather than

> *Estamos muy emocionados de que vengas por navidad*

(which is absolutely correct Spanish), we would avoid words such as being *emocionado*, *encantado*, *entusiasmado*, or even *estar deseando algo*, and do some unconscious "workaround" instead, like:

> *¡A ver si nos vemos ya pronto, en Navidad!*
>
> *¡Nos vemos la semana que viene!*

This doesn't mean you can't use an affective intonation, of course :)

Comment: But Mexicans on the other hand are more likely to convey their emotions directly.

Comment: In Colombia it's quite common to say "Que emoción que vengas para navidad"

Comment: The statement _"... Spaniards are really not likely to convey their emotions as directly as English speakers do"_ sounds weird to me. I've never heard something like that, but just the opposite. Is there any fact to support such statement?

Answer (score 3):

Just to add another option, in Spanish (at least in Spain) you can use the word **[ilusión](http://dle.rae.es/?id=KzR4947)**:

> 2. f. Esperanza cuyo cumplimiento parece especialmente atractivo.

You can use it by saying that something *te hace ilusión*. So, taking your examples:

- ¡Me hace ilusión verte la semana que viene!
- La graduación le hace mucha ilusión.
- ¡Qué ilusión nos hace que vengas a vernos en Navidad!

In English, one of the meanings of *to excite* is *to cause feelings of enthusiasm in (someone)*. In Spanish, *hacer ilusión* means roughly the same. You can also say *estar ilusionado*, but the expression *hacer ilusión* sounds more natural for me.

Note that not every instance of *excite* can be translated this way. For instance, you can't use *ilusión* in *the movie was very exciting*. The problem with *excite* is that it implies "to arouse an emotional response", but that emotion can be any. The direct translation (*excitar*) carries a bit of a sexual meaning in Spain. So we try to translate it by using the particular feeling the original text refers to.

Comment: Not just Spain.  Great answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think *emocionado* is a internal feeling:

- Estoy emocionado, no tengo palabras (I can't talk).

*Entusiasmado* is a feeling that you can't help but show:

- Estoy entusiasmado, no puedo dejar de sonreir ( I can't stop smiling).